# I'm having a problem with gpiozero LED's on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, led

I've got a breadboard HAT attached on my raspberry pi. I've got 2 circuits, one with a green LED and one with a red LED. I start explaining my problem right away but it's better for you to have the code I wrote.

```
from gpiozero import LED
from time import sleep
import random
led_g = LED(4)
led_r = LED(17)
i = 0
n = 0
print("How many equations do you want to make?")
s = float(input())
while n < s:
    a = random.randint(1,10)
    b = random.randint(1,10)
    q = a + b
    print("What is", a , "+", b, "?")
    x = float(input())
    while i <= 10:
       if x == q:
          led_g.on()
          sleep(0.1)
          led_g.off()
          sleep(0.1)
          i += 1
       if x != q:
          led_r.on()
          sleep(0.1)
          led_r.off()
          sleep(0.1)
          i += 1
    n += 1
```

Knowing that you know the code I can explain it much better:
I've got a red light attached to GPIO17 : led_r = LED(17)
I've also got a green light attached to GPIO4: led_g = LED(4)
When you answer the random generated equation correctly I want the green light to blink ten times, if its a wrong answer i want the red light to blink ten times.
If you answer the first equation right or wrong respectively the green or red LED will blink 10 times. But when answering all equations after that, the lights don't blink anymore. This is my problem. I want the lights to blink after every equation. Not only for the first one. I can't see what I've done wrong in my code.
Sorry for putting in all my code but in my opinion its all used to explain my problem.

Comment: After the first answer, `i` will have a value of 11.  The `while` loop will not be entered on subsequent answers, because its condition is false from the start.  You'd need to reset `i` just before the loop, rather than once at the start of the code.  (Also note that an incorrect answer turns red on, but green off, so it wouldn't actually blink.)

Comment: Hey, thank you for your comment. Thanks, I understand the problem now.. It was actually quite logical. Though, how can I reset the i before the while loop? Can I do it with the standard python functions? Also, thanks for pointing it out to me but the incorrect answer turning the green LED on was just a typo of mine ;) . I couldn't copy the code from my PI so I had to manually re-write it.

Comment: You just need to move the `i = 0` to a different point.